# Azure App Services Enforce HTTPS for only for one/specific custom domain/s

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-app-service, custom-domain

I have an Azure App service and it has multiple custom domains mapped. When I enforce HTTPS from SSL Configuration it applied all custom domains.

[image]

Is there any way to enforce HTTPS only for one/specific custom domain/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we could not enforce HTTPS only for one/specific custom domain/s.

As I check the `httpsOnly` in the **Azure Resource Explorer** (you can access it in the **DEVELOPMENT TOOLS** in the portal), the property is for the whole web app and we could not set it to specific domain.

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/joywebapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/joywebapp2",
  "name": "joywebapp2",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "app",
  "location": "Central US",
  "properties": {
      ........
     "httpsOnly": true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now Azure App Services has the option to enforce HTTPS for only for one/specific custom domain/s using:

Azure portal > App Services > Click on webapp > Settings > Custom domains

In this section Set `HTTPS only` to `On`